# How to process the incoming streaming json data in java from spark consumer

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, hadoop-streaming

Below are my code snippet and the JSON data streaming into the consumer.But not able to understand how can I do the computations with the data.

```
public void sparkKafkaConsumer(JavaStreamingContext jssc,String zkBroker,Map<String, Integer> topicmap, SQLContext sqlContext) throws InterruptedException  {
    System.out.println("INSIDE SPARK KAFKACONSUMER METHOD..........");


    System.out.println("Creating direct kafka stream with brokers and topics..........");
    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zkBroker,"CustomerKafkaConsumerThread", topicmap,StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());

    System.out.println("Computation starts from here");
    messages.print();
```

**Below is the JSON data received.**

```
> (null,{"time":"2017/07/12
> 11:26:47","model":"20optky","speed":"20optky","cellId":"0605d822optky","course":"146.37optky","header":"ST600ALToptky","deviceId":"206675884optky","distance":"166optky","longitude":"-099.168493optky","latitude":"19.428616optky","payload":"ST600ALT+number+;206675884;20;376;20161005;16:26:59;0605d822;334;20;2ee5;63;+19.428616;-099.168493;000.213;146.37;6;1;166;12.21;000000;34;000887;4.4;1;0.00optky","date":"2017/07/12
> 11:26:47optky"})
```

Please note I am using spark version 1.5.2, Hence DataFrame is not supported.

Comment: It's basically a `Tuple2`, right? You can use any JSON parser to get the data from that JSON.

Comment: json.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
         @Override
         public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
             if(!rdd.isEmpty()){
I am getting error on json.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {, . What is the issue?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you'd like to do with the JSON. BTW, 1.5.2 is pretty old. You should consider upgrading and get JSON support on DataFrames for free.

Comment: @maasg I am planning to extract each key value of the JSON data,compute it and save it in DB.
I have updated to 2.0.0. Thanks

Comment: So, what's the question? What are you having issues with? There're plenty of Q/As here that deal with this. Maybe search first through the site?